# Right Click Not Working Why?

Tags: touchpad, lenovo, ideapad

Right Click Not Working.
Right Click Also Do the Work of left click. if i click right click twice it acts like left click.

why this problem?
2  Days Worked fine am new for ubuntu
Using Lenovo Ideapad 320E Laptop
Touchpad working fine in Windows Operating system

Please Help me

Comment: Need more info. Have you tried an external mouse? Does it work? While many people have laptops, not all have the same one so you might describe how you do the "right click".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The functionality of right click can perhaps be achieved by a two finger tap and that of left click by a one finger tap. I hope this helps. I'm not sure which version of Ubuntu you are talking about, but the above feature is in Ubuntu 18.04.